# How to generate facebook page tokens dynamically for different users of my app. I want different users to post to the pages directly from my app

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I generate facebook page tokens dynamically with python for different users of my app? I want different users to post to their own pages directly from my app. most of the solutions I have seen and tried allows for posting to one page that doesn't change

Comment: They can post to their own pages with a normal token acquired via OAuth2. You just need to request the right scopes ("permissions" in Facebook wording) to make posts. Or do you want them to post **as** the page?

Comment: thanks for the insight@KlausD. The user's pages are official pages for their businesses. I intended to enable them to post as a page, hence the need for a page token. I thought of using the user token to generate that but I can't find my way around it (I am not sure if i am on the right track). Please help

Comment: thanks a lot @KlausD. one can get all the pages a user is subscribed to including the permissions and their respective access_tokens. It worked for me. I was requesting via https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?     instead of   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?